# Which Found Bodies Don't Ruin the Silent Assassin Rating?

Tags: hitman-2-2018

In what cases is it permissible to let bodies be found without risking a loss of the Silent Assassin rating in a mission? Experience with the results of such findings seems inconsistent:

- Poisoning the Revolutionary (Elusive Target), and letting the NPCs find the body, granted a Silent Assassin rating.
- Conversely, various *accident* kills seem to ruin the Silent Assassin rating, such as burning/exploding Penelope Graves or Maya Parvati in the return to Colorado  due to bodies being found.

What are the rules about which bodies count as rating-ruining and which aren't?

Answer (score 1):

Bodies which have suffered an accident or have been poisoned do not count as "found bodies", *provided that they are your targets.* Non-Target kills ruin the Slient Assasin rating, as can commonly occur with the accident with the battering ram that kills Parvati.

Comment: Then why is Parvati burned by the fuel tank ruin the SA rating, as an example?

Comment: @vicky_molokh It didn't for me. Were you spotted setting it off? If she spots you right before dying it might count as being spotted.

Comment: There was no alert at the time, but the Found Bodies score was penalised to 0.

Comment: @vicky_molokh Weird. I might not have done the same kill as you. The big big fuel tank or the barrel of oil next to the garage that's right nearby it? And how did you set it off?

Comment: Fuel tank leak near the garage. For the Challenge. With Krugermeier 2-2. Notably, I didn't even raise suspicion